# Control authentication dialog in SharePoint 2010 using SSO

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sso

External facing website.

Using Sharepoint 2010 SP2 + SSO using a trusted Id Provider (Salesforce). 
Users can browse anonymously. On login they are redirected to the IdP.
This works.

However the website hosts webservices that need forms authentication.

Once I enable forms authentication, on login users are prompted with a dialog asking them to choose between Salesforce and Forms Authentication.

Is there a way to suppress this dialog and use the the trusted IdP in all scenarios other than the webservice (which must continue to use forms?)

[This link suggests that you can make changes to the webconfig to suppress the dialog, but that had no effect](http://blog.techgalaxy.net/archives/3118)

```
<security>
<requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping=”true”>
<verbs allowUnlisted=”true”>
<add verb=”OPTIONS” allowed=”false” />
<add verb=”PROPFIND” allowed=”false” />
</verbs>
</requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Any  help would be greatly appreciated.